# Change Text Of A UILabel To A Random Array Object By Pressing UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title says... I need to change the contents of my UILabel to a random object from NSArray by pressing a UIButton... Here is the code i have in the button:

```
- (IBAction)moodButton:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UILabel *moodLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSArray *moodArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Happy", @"Angry", @"Sad", @"Bored",
                              @"Tired", @"Stressed", @"Busy", nil];
        id randomObject = [moodArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([moodArray count])];

        if (randomObject == moodArray[0]) {
            moodLabel.text = @"Happy";
        }
        else if (randomObject == moodArray[1]) {
            moodLabel.text = @"Angry";
        }
        else if (randomObject == moodArray[2]) {
            moodLabel.text = @"Sad";
        }
        else if (randomObject == moodArray[3]) {
            moodLabel.text = @"Bored";
        }
        else if (randomObject == moodArray[4]) {
            moodLabel.text = @"Tired";
        }
        else if (randomObject == moodArray[5]) {
            moodLabel.text = @"Stressed";
        }
        else if (randomObject == moodArray[6]) {
            moodLabel.text = @"Busy";
        }

}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong??? Is it crashing??? Is the label not updating???

Comment: The label is not updating... Sorry should've mentioned this

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues with your code.

1. You're creating a new label and then doing nothing with it other than adding some text (not even adding it to another view). Do you have an existing label you want to use instead? I'd recommend you keep a property pointing to a label in your view, which you can use to just update the text.
2. Your entire `if` statement is completely redundant. `randomObject` already contains a random string from your array, so you don't need to manually check which value it contains. Just remove your whole `if` statement, and do:

   `moodLabel.text = (NSString *)randomObject;`

Comment: Also - does your button have multiple functions? One for a normal tap and one for a tap-and-hold? Just wondering why you're using a gesture recognizer on it.

Comment: No I have only got the long hold one on it :)

Comment: And `randomObject` should just be an `NSString`, not an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by James covers the issues but I thought I would clarify by showing some code.

```
- (IBAction)moodButton:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSArray *moodArray = @[ @"Happy", @"Angry", @"Sad", @"Bored",
                              @"Tired", @"Stressed", @"Busy" ];

        NSString *randomString = moodArray[arc4random_uniform([moodArray count])];

        self.moodLabel.text = randomString;
    }
}
```

Note how the label is needs to be obtained from the existing label. Don't create a new one. Also note the use of modern Objective-C syntax for the array and its access.

Comment: No, I took that out. I was briefly confused. :)

Comment: Did you fix how you get a reference to the existing label? You don't provide enough details to know how you need to access the existing label.

Comment: You put the label that you want to update. You must already have a label, right? Use a reference to that label. The problem with the code in your question is that you create a new label and update that. You need to update the label that already exists and is already on the screen.

Comment: Yes it should and that is the label you should reference in this code.

Comment: If `self.moodLabel.text = randomString;` doesn't update the label then either the outlet isn't connected or this code isn't even being called. Have you checked both?

Comment: I think I found the problem... When I go into the split editor it isn't finding the ViewController.m file. Does that mean it's not finding the code for my button when it needs it?

Comment: I think you need to go find a Hello World tutorial to get a grasp on how to use UIViews and objective-C properties